# How to mask system modules at runtime?

Tags: java-9, java-module

I want to create a module layer configuration at runtime, that consists of a subset of system modules provided by a default JRE. Basically the same as what you can achieve with `jlink` -- but at runtime.

The following snippets show the outline of my current non-working solution. The calling block looks like:

```
ClassLoader loader = createCustomClassLoader("java.base", "java.logging");

assertNotNull(loader.loadClass("java.util.logging.Logger"));
assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> loader.loadClass("javax.script.ScriptEngine"));
```

The ClassLoader factory is:

```
private ClassLoader createTestClassLoader(String... rootNames) {
  ModuleFinder before = ModuleFinder.of();
  List<Configuration> parents = List.of(ModuleLayer.boot().configuration());
  ModuleFinder after = ModuleFinder.of();

  Configuration configuration = Configuration.resolve(before, parents, after, Arrays.asList(rootNames));    

  ClassLoader parentLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
  ModuleLayer configuredLayer = ModuleLayer.boot().defineModulesWithOneLoader(configuration, parentLoader);

  ClassLoader classLoader = configuredLayer.findLoader(rootNames[rootNames.length-1]);
  assertNotNull(classLoader); // classLoader is null (***)
  classLoader.setDefaultAssertionStatus(true); // -ea
  return classLoader;
}
```

Is this *masking* of system modules possible at runtime? If yes, how?

Comment: The problem is that the loader in the newly created layer has a class loader as parent that sees `javax.script.ScriptEngine`. No matter how you create the layer, as long as that's true, you'll always be able to load that class.

Comment: I wonder whether the layer you create actually contains _java.logging_. That module is already present in the parent layer (unless you launched with `--limit-modules`), so maybe it's not added to the new layer? Or maybe it is because it's a root module? On a hunch, check whether the class loader your method returns is one of the three class loaders of the base layer.

Comment: Custom layers cannot contain modules with java.* packages. In any case, I don't think you need any code for this, instead all you need is `java --limit-modules java.logging`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Using `java --limit-modules` as suggested and asserting that certain messages are rendered to the standard output stream.